# IE 7 issues: Super simple page - TD height not taking effect

Tags: html, css

This is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test title</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         *
         {
            margin:0px auto;
            padding:0px;
         }
         html,body
         {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
         <tr>
            <td style="height:55px;background:#CCC;" valign="top">
               <h1>Header</h1>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               Content @RenderBody()
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="height:85px;background:#CCC;" valign="bottom">
               Footer
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody tell me why td height is not taking effect? This same markup works in IE9. Is it due to the HTML5 doctype?

Comment: You get errors if you run this through the W3C validator. Maybe fix those, first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should definitely rethink your approach to page layout.  Tables should only be used for presenting tabular data rather than setting page layouts.  You should look into Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) and layout elements such as DIV's if possible.

Addressing the question however, the height styles seem to apply in Chrome, and are valid as per the information here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp.

As suggested above, try running your code through the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/.

I would still recommend abandoning the use of tables if possible, and use an external CSS instead of inline styles to style up your elements as this is a much more modern, flexible and semantically correct approach.  You may be following some outdated tutorials.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing how you were able to conclude from the information that Anthony gave you, that the contents of his table is not tabular data!

Comment: You're right, it was an assumption based on loading the code in a browser and noticing that it looks like, with the 100% width and height, he's attempting to do some kind of layout with the table.  From my experience (I've been building websites since 1994), most tabular data doesn't have a single column with 3 rows, one with Header, another with Content, and another with Footer.  Nor is the header and footer column presumably deliberately pinned to the top and bottom of the browser window.  Perhaps Anthony can clear up this issue so we can provide more appropriate feedback.

Comment: @Alex: This is a demo page. I hope that is clear from the inline styles that I have used. I am not a designer by trade but I guess I know this much about designing ;). And yes I want to use tables only. It's representing tabular data only. Perhaps I should change the Header to Row 1 and Footer to Row 3 to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for the clarification.  If you want a header and footer in your table, it's more semantically correct to use the <thead>, <tfoot> and <tbody> examples, as per the examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Answer (score 0):

No its not due to html5 doctype.

Your `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height:100%">` causing the problem in IE7,

Please remove `height:100%` from  this, and give your content a suitable height.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
                <title>Test title</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    *
                    {
                        margin:0px auto;
                        padding:0px;
                    }
                    html,body
                    {
                        height:100%;
                        width:100%;
                    }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="height:55px;background:#CCC;" valign="top">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="position:relative; height:100px;">
                        Content @RenderBody()
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="height:85px;background:#CCC;" valign="bottom">
                        Footer
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And please follow the general way of making html/css markup as other answers suggesting .

Hope this will help